# Fetching host availability to external webpage in Nagios

Tags: linux, api, monitoring, nagios

Is there any possible way to fetch the live availability of host/host group from Nagios monitoring tool (where host/hostgroups are already configured) which can be redirected/captured to an external webpage.
are there any exposed API's to do that, couldn't found a way.
Nagios is on a Linux host.
Any help or info is appreciated.

EDIT1:

I have a hostgroup say for example 'All_prod' in this hostgroup I will be having around 20 linux hosts for all the host there would be some metrics/checks defined (example availability, cpu load, free memory ..etc). Here I want the report of only availability metrics of all the host(example : lets say if in 24 hours if the availability is down for 10 minutes then it should provide me with the report as it was down for 10 minutes in 24 hours or just give me any related info which i can evaluate using data evaluation).
it would be great if there are any API's to fetch that information, which will return the data as json/xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Nagios JSON API. You can use the query builder here http://NAGIOSURL/jsonquery.html.

But, to answer your specific question, the queries for hosts would look like this:

http://NAGIOSURL/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=host&hostname=localhost

Which will output something similar to the following:

```
{
    "format_version": 0,
    "result": {
        "query_time": 1497384499000,
        "cgi": "statusjson.cgi",
        "user": "nagiosadmin",
        "query": "host",
        "query_status": "released",
        "program_start": 1497368240000,
        "last_data_update": 1497384489000,
        "type_code": 0,
        "type_text": "Success",
        "message": ""
    },
    "data": {
        "host": {
            "name": "localhost",
            "plugin_output": "egsdda",
            "long_plugin_output": "",
            "perf_data": "",
            "status": 8,
            "last_update": 1497384489000,
            "has_been_checked": true,
            "should_be_scheduled": false,
            "current_attempt": 10,
            "max_attempts": 10,
            "last_check": 1496158536000,
            "next_check": 0,
            "check_options": 0,
            "check_type": 1,
            "last_state_change": 1496158536000,
            "last_hard_state_change": 1496158536000,
            "last_hard_state": 1,
            "last_time_up": 1496158009000,
            "last_time_down": 1496158536000,
            "last_time_unreachable": 1480459504000,
            "state_type": 1,
            "last_notification": 1496158536000,
            "next_notification": 1496165736000,
            "no_more_notifications": false,
            "notifications_enabled": true,
            "problem_has_been_acknowledged": false,
            "acknowledgement_type": 0,
            "current_notification_number": 2,
            "accept_passive_checks": true,
            "event_handler_enabled": true,
            "checks_enabled": false,
            "flap_detection_enabled": true,
            "is_flapping": false,
            "percent_state_change": 0,
            "latency": 0.49,
            "execution_time": 0,
            "scheduled_downtime_depth": 0,
            "process_performance_data": true,
            "obsess": true
        }
    }
}
```

And for hostgroups:

http://NAGIOSURL/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=hostlist&hostgroup=linux-servers

Which will output something similar to the following:

```
{
  "format_version": 0,
  "result": {
    "query_time": 1497384613000,
    "cgi": "statusjson.cgi",
    "user": "nagiosadmin",
    "query": "hostlist",
    "query_status": "released",
    "program_start": 1497368240000,
    "last_data_update": 1497384609000,
    "type_code": 0,
    "type_text": "Success",
    "message": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "selectors": {
      "hostgroup": "linux-servers"
    },
    "hostlist": {
      "localhost": 8
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT 1 (To correspond with the question's EDIT 1):

What you're asking for isn't built in by default. You can use the above methods to grab the data for each host (but it sounds like you want it for each service), so **again** we will use the JSON API found at http://YOURNAGIOSURL/jsonquery.html to grab service data..

http://YOURNAGIOSURL/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=service&hostname=localhost&servicedescription=Current+Load

We'll get the following output (something similar, anyway):

```
{
    "format_version": 0,
    "result": {
        "query_time": 1497875258000,
        "cgi": "statusjson.cgi",
        "user": "nagiosadmin",
        "query": "service",
        "query_status": "released",
        "program_start": 1497800686000,
        "last_data_update": 1497875255000,
        "type_code": 0,
        "type_text": "Success",
        "message": ""
    },
    "data": {
        "service": {
            "host_name": "localhost",
            "description": "Current Load",
            "plugin_output": "OK - load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00",
            "long_plugin_output": "",
            "perf_data": "load1=0.000;5.000;10.000;0; load5=0.000;4.000;6.000;0; load15=0.000;3.000;4.000;0;",
            "max_attempts": 4,
            "current_attempt": 1,
            "status": 2,
            "last_update": 1497875255000,
            "has_been_checked": true,
            "should_be_scheduled": true,
            "last_check": 1497875014000,
            "check_options": 0,
            "check_type": 0,
            "checks_enabled": true,
            "last_state_change": 1497019191000,
            "last_hard_state_change": 1497019191000,
            "last_hard_state": 0,
            "last_time_ok": 1497875014000,
            "last_time_warning": 1497019191000,
            "last_time_unknown": 0,
            "last_time_critical": 1497018891000,
            "state_type": 1,
            "last_notification": 0,
            "next_notification": 0,
            "next_check": 1497875314000,
            "no_more_notifications": false,
            "notifications_enabled": true,
            "problem_has_been_acknowledged": false,
            "acknowledgement_type": 0,
            "current_notification_number": 0,
            "accept_passive_checks": true,
            "event_handler_enabled": true,
            "flap_detection_enabled": true,
            "is_flapping": false,
            "percent_state_change": 0,
            "latency": 0,
            "execution_time": 0,
            "scheduled_downtime_depth": 0,
            "process_performance_data": true,
            "obsess": true
        }
    }
}
```

The most important line for what you're trying to do (as far as I understand it) is the perfdata line:

```
"perf_data": "load1=0.000;5.000;10.000;0; load5=0.000;4.000;6.000;0; load15=0.000;3.000;4.000;0;",
```

This is the data you'd use to generate whatever custom metrics report you're trying to generate.

Keep in mind this is something that is sort of built in to Nagios XI (not in an exportable format like you're requesting) but the metrics component does allow you to easily drill down and take a look at some metric specific data.

Hope **this** helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question was regarding availability for the host.
for example if I have a linux host in the host group "ubuntu12.04" then will i get the availability status for the same host by any queries?

Comment: Are you asking about the host's status? As in, is it UP or DOWN? If not, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Ok so here is the scenario I have edited the question(EDIT 1)  and provided example case.

Comment: EDIT 1 should reflect an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation it gave a good insight , but the concern is we want the timelog data when the service status was down/up

Comment: You can definitely do what you're trying to do - there are several different endpoints in the core API. There is object/status/archive - you would want to specify time points in archive based on service detail status information it sounds like. A bit more complicated, but definitely doable :)

Comment: Im trying to fetch availablity report from http://NAGIOS_URL/nagios/jsonquery.html. How to define DateFormat, Start Time and EndTime field to fetch availability report